# IE 6/7 and floats

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

My forehead is bruised out of frustration over this issue. In the standards compliant browsers my layout looks fine but, of course, IE7 and IE6 like to make a hot mess of everything. I'm trying to make a simple header that has some text to the left and a form inline on the right. The header is 835px wide and centered using auto margins. Here is my code:

```
<div id="header"> 
    <span>Some Text</span>
        <div style="display: inline; float: right; margin-top: 6px; position: relative;">
            Jump to: <form ... style="display: inline;"> blah blah </form> 
        </div>
</div>
```

As far as I can tell IE6/7 are treating the div containing the form as a block element. It is correctly displayed on the right of the header div but gets pushed down. I have tried giving the inner div a width  and absolute position but to no avail. I would actually like to avoid absolute positioning as well as conditional statements if possible. There has to be something I'm overlooking. Any suggestions?

UPDATE: Here is a screenshot from IE7
[alt text http://vincentalcivar.com/ie7.png](http://vincentalcivar.com/ie7.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `<span>Some Text</span>` to `<span style="float: left;">Some Text</span>`.

Also, you might want to remove to remove `margin-top: 6px; position: relative;` from the `DIV`.

**Edit:** Here's the code.

```
<div id="header"> 
  <span style="float: left;">Some Text</span>
  <div style="display: inline; float: right;">
    Jump to: <form style="display: inline; margin: 0;"> blah blah </form> 
  </div>
  &nbsp;
</div>
```

Added a `&nbsp;` (and removed the `overflow: auto;`), since IE6 thinks that the line has no content after the floats.

Comment: This seems to work for IE, but causes the rest of the browsers to display the rest of the page content improperly. I'll look into maybe changing the properties of the other elements and see if that works.

Comment: hmm. So far the solution seems to be adding <div style="clear: both;"></div> after the inner div, and that clears up the problem with the rest of the content and also makes it render fine in every browser. It's probably not the most elegant solution though since it adds more markup. Is there a better way?

Comment: Now it works nicely in all browsers... and yes, in IE6 as well. :)

Comment: Ok so, I added overflow: auto and removed the clear and that seemed to do the trick. There was slight problem with FF in Mac Os X that caused the horizontal scrollbar to appear, so I added a width to the inner div and that seemed to clear it up. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you've marked up the elements like you have, but for some text to the left and a form to the right, I would have done the following:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="text_holder">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor set amet.</p>
    </div>
    <form>
        ...
    </form>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
#header {
    width: 835px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
#text_holder {
    float: left;
}
#header form {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to IE6/7 at the moment. However, there are float bugs with each of those browsers. Adding CSS property of `zoom: 1` will trigger `hasLayout` for these elements and help them render *as expected*.

Although you don't need to add this via a conditional stylesheet, I would recommend it as it is a browser specific fix.

It is possible that some of your other styles are conflicting. I am not sure if you were attempting to fix the issue, but `display: inline` shouldn't be necessary.

It may help to post a screenshot of how things look in IE6/7.